# Change title page template in beamer

Tags: beamer

I would like to change the `title page` in beamer. Thus I tried to change it with `defbeamertemplate` as you can see above :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{A title}
\date{\today}
\institute{home}
\author{me}
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{default}[1][]
{
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{plop}
    plop

    plop
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that even with a simple example such as above, I got the following error message :

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \beamer@@tmpop@title page@default already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

actually the page 192 of the manual does not help me so much ...

Comment: Try `\setbeamertemplate`.

Comment: Ok it works, but why it leads to an error with `title page` and not with `headline`, `footline` or other template ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With

```
\defbeamertemplate{<element>}{<option>}
```

you install an `<option>` for the template called `<element>`; once this has been done, the defined template can be used with

```
\setbeamertemplate{<element>}[<option>]
```

In your case you get an error message since the `default` option for the `title page` template is already defined. You can use

```
\defbeamertemplate{title page}{<name>}
{
<some actions>
}
```

(the syntax for `\defbeamertemplate` is more complex, but this is not relevant here), if the option  has not been previously defined for the template, and then use

```
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[<name>]
```

but since this is a local modification (intended to be used in a document and not, for example, in the design of a new theme), it's simpler to just use

```
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
<some actions>
}
```